# Registering a closed generic class implementation with an opened generic interface

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-3.1, scrutor, netcore.autoregisterdi

I've just realized, that you can't register a dependency injection like this:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IConcreteRepository<,>), typeof(DepartmentRepository));
```

DI forbids registering non-generic class with generic interface.

```
public interface IConcreteRepository<TEntity, TId> : IRepository<TEntity, TId> where TEntity : class
{}

public abstract class BaseEntityFrameworkRepository<TEntity, TId> : IConcreteRepository<TEntity, TId> where TEntity : class where TId: struct
{}

public class DepartmentRepository : BaseEntityFrameworkRepository<Department, int>
{}
```

---

Are there any 3rd party DI libraries that can make registering `DepartmentRepository` with `IConcreteRepository<,>` possible?

I need a solution of this problem no matter the library - if it's possible with the default .NET Core 3 framework it would be fantastic, but if there are any 3rd party libraries that can make this possible, I'm ok as well.

---

EDIT:

I should mention that registering like this throws the following exception:

```
An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. 

Error: Open generic service type 'CompanyName.ApplicationName.DAL.Repository.Contracts.IConcreteRepository`2[TEntity,TId]' requires registering an open generic implementation type. (Parameter 'descriptors').
```

Comment: but `DepartmentRepository` is not `IConcreteRepository<,>`. What actually you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @GuruStron I'm a little confused about DI, sorry. Is it not possible to register the `DepartmentRepository` with `IConcreteRepository`? `DepartmentRepository` inherits from an abstract class that implements the interface.

Comment: You can register `DepartmentRepository` as `IConcreteRepository<Department, int>` and this would make sense. I see no point in registering it as `IConcreteRepository<,>`, but open for explanations.

Comment: @GuruStron `services.AddScoped(typeof(IConcreteRepository<Department, int>), typeof(DepartmentRepository));` this throws `Error: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: DepartmentRepository can't be converted to service type IConcreteRepository'[Department, Int32]'`

Comment: Try `services.AddScoped<IConcreteRepository<Department, int>, DepartmentRepository>()`, it works in my test project.

Comment: @GuruStron You are a genius. Thank you so much. You should write an answer to mark it as a solution! This works perfectly. Well it doesn't work on my Decorated repositories, but this is another topic. I will post another question if I can't manage them to work. Thanks again!

Comment: Was glad to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should register your repository as closed generic interface:

```
services.AddScoped<IConcreteRepository<Department, int>, DepartmentRepository>();
```